# How to find all tables that contain columnA and columnB

Tags: mysql, sql, select, information-schema

I want to achieve something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'columnA'
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'columnB';
```

But this specific query will return 0 coincidences.

Comment: Try this SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnA','ColumnB')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each row in `information_schema.columns` represents a single column - it can't be both `columnA` and `columnB`. One approach could be to count the number of such columns in a table and check which return two results:

```
SELECT   table_name
FROM     information_schema.columns
WHERE    column_name IN ('COLUMNA', 'COLUMNB')
GROUP BY table_name
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work. i tested it with a table, typed 2 columns of that table and the query didn't return that table. It returned 0 coincidences.

Comment: @Krotanix lapsed concentration there. The `group by` was wrong, and should have been by the `table_name`. Edited and fixed - please try now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OR and not and  ..

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'columnA'
OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'columnB';
```

is not possible that in the same row a column contain 'columnA' AND 'columnB'

But if you need  the table name with both you could use a inner join

```
SELECT DISTINCT C1.TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'columnB'
) C2 ON C1.TABLE_NAME = C2.TABLE_NAME
WHERE C2.COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'columnA'
```

Comment: But I only want to see the tables that contain both columns, not either one or the other. I tested it and it doesn't solve my need. Feel free to completely change my query as long as it finds all tables that contain both column names.

Comment: Thanks, but not I get: Error Code: 1052. Column 'TABLE_NAME' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Still getting an error. Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'C1.COLUMN_NAME' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Krotanix   .answer updated .. removing an unseful c1  in inner select  ..  hope is  right now  ..  let me know